# How to store a Geolocation in HTML?

Tags: html, encoding, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, latitude-longitude

On my website I want to share a geolocation on which mobile users can click on and then navigation to this location using the users preferred maps app installed on their device.

So I'm aiming to be independent of any maps provider and hence don't want to provide a Link to the API of such. I simply want to encode the longitude and latitude values in  a way the user can easily work with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are refering to mobile users, aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the [Geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme), where a link could look like this:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677">Map</a>
```

Comment: That looks promising. I'll try that and let you know if works. Thanks!!